# How to get the active route in app.component

Tags: angular

I want to get the active route in app.component so I can hide some elements in my app header.

For instance, if route /assets,

I set the `isHeader: boolean = true;`

I get an object when I do this:

```
import {Router, ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';

 constructor(router: ActivatedRoute) {
   this.route = router.url;
   console.log(this.route);
}
```

How can I get the route value /assets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to "listen" to the router-events.

See my plunker for a working demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/XJmOa7rmtvBpuJDfQ2Vd?p=preview

The interesting part is this code snippet:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
    </div>
    <a routerLink="/cmp1">cmp1</a><br />
    <a routerLink="/cmp2">cmp2</a><br />
    <a routerLink="/cmp3">cmp3</a><br />

    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  constructor(private _r: Router) {
    this.name = 'Angular2'

    this._r.events.subscribe(event => {
      if (event instanceof RoutesRecognized) {
        console.log('navigated to:', event.url);
        console.log('route state', event.state);
        console.log('');
      }
      else if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        // if u dont need the state, you could even use this event-type..
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Subscribe to the router-events and check which type of event was fired.
If you want to use the state (params, queryParams, ...) i recommend to use `RoutesRecognized`-event-type. but you can even use `NavigationEnd`-event-type if you only want to get the current `url`..

Comment: I tried this in my app.component but still ain't getting nothing.

Comment: please post more details.. what is 'nothing'? maybe update your question with more code..

Comment: it works well getting the route from each component. But my idea is to get the route in my main app.component. I don't know it that make sense.

Comment: You are right, `ActivatedRoute` won't work on AppComponent.. See my updated answer!